# Is there a better way I can make/present my list?

Tags: python, list, output, modulo

**This question has been updated:**

I managed to get my program to print what I wanted by introducing a for loop and using only one list instead of two. Like this:

```
   while i <= rows:
    j = 1
    while j <= seats:
        k = j+(4*(i-1))
        field.append("{}".format(k))  #Adds the two values to one.
        j += 1
    i += 1

a = 1
b = 1
for isle in range(rows):
    for column in range(seats):
        if a == 13:
            print(" ↓ TYST AVD ↓")
        if a % 4 != 0:
            print(field[a-1].ljust(4), end='')
        else:
            print(field[a-1].ljust(4), end=''+"\n")
        a += 1
b += 1
```

This prints out:

```
1   2   3   4   
5   6   7   8   
9   10  11  12  
 ↓ TYST AVD ↓
13  14  15  16  
17  18  19  20  
21  22  23  24
```

My issue is to get every other row to be reversed, i.e. I want this:

```
1   2   3   4   
8   7   6   5   
9   10  11  12  
 ↓ TYST AVD ↓
16  15  14  13  
17  18  19  20  
24  23  22  21
```

I've tried implementing modulo in a few different ways but I can't seem to get it to work. Is this plausible to do with modulo or do I have to rethink everything?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Please work through a tutorial on output formatting.  Look for how to specify a field width.

Answer (score 3):

Check if `s` is a list or string. If it's a string, print it normally rather than spreading it into multiple arguments.

```
for s in field:
    if isinstance(s, list):
        print(*s)
    else:
        print(s)
```